# WPF Telerik DataFormCombobbox losed its selected item in edit mode

Tags: wpf, telerik, dataform

I am using WPF Telerik dataform & Grid, I have set the auto generate columns to false for the dataform where as I set it true for the grid.

DataFormCombobox loses its selected item when I enter edit mode in the data form. Please some one help.

Regards,
Kannan M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer myself, It looks like it happens only when I use DataFormCombobox, When I change it to DataFormDataField inside which I kept the RadCombobox, and set the same binding which had no such issue.It's a workaround but I could not se any other option.